GoogleのInstanceIDAPIが利用不可はいつからでしょうか
Googleが提供しているインスタンスIDAPIのリファレンスページに、「Instance ID API のサポートは終了しました。」と記載されていました。
このAPIサービスが利用できなくなる日はいつからでしょうか？

「サポートは終了しました」= 過去形の表現なので、既に終了したと考えるのが自然ではないでしょうか。
